# Commerce payment currencies

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

admin/commerce/store-settings/paymentcurrencies

There is no Croatia on currency list HRK
How to solve that...

Is it possible (in Craft Commerce V2) to have multi STOCK location fields for products

1 product can be on different locations in same time

Comment: Is this Commerce 1 or Commerce 2?

Comment: commerce 2.. latest one.. couple days ago...installed